# How can I generate an "unlimited" world?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, random

I would like to create a game with an endless (in reality an extremely large) world in which the player can move about. Whether or not I will ever get around to implement the game is one matter, but I find the idea interesting and would like some input on how to do it.

The point is to have a world where all data is generated randomly on-demand, but in a *deterministic* way.

Currently I focus on a large 2D map from which it should be possible to display any part without knowledge about the surrounding parts.

I have implemented a prototype by writing a function that gives a random-looking, but deterministic, integer given the x and y of a pixel on the map (see [my recent question about this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043521/a-function-where-small-changes-in-input-always-result-in-large-changes-in-output)). Using this function I populate the map with "random" values, and then I smooth the map using a simple filter based on the surrounding pixels. This makes the map dependent on a few pixels outside its edge, but that's not a big problem. The final result is something that at least looks like a map (especially with a good altitude color map). Given this, one could maybe first generate a coarser map which is used to generate bigger differences in altitude to create mountain ranges and seas.

Anyway, that was *my* idea, but I am sure that there exist ways to do this already and I also believe that given the specification, many of you can come up with better ideas.

**EDIT:** 
Forgot the link to my question.

**EDIT 2:**
I think I'll have to clarify that it is important that two adjacent parts of the map, generated separately, needs to smoothly connect to each other.

**EDIT 3:**
Some more information was asked for in the comments.

Here's an image taken [from a page about fractal and Perlin Noise](http://www.neilblevins.com/cg_education/fractal_noise/fractal_noise.html) that looks much like what I have produced myself previously (since my best attempt probably used Perlin Noise):

[image]

Think of black pixels as deep sea and white pixels as mountain tops. This is what I need, a simple 2D elevation map.

What I want to be able to do is to pick any rectangle from the very large world (in the range of MAXINT * MAXINT pixels) and generate it. If I would generate any part of the image above it should get exactly the same pixels as if I generated a bigger part encompassing the smaller one.

Now on to Unreason's questions:

*Required performance*: My main aim would be a turn based RPG, so performance could be quite low, but I think it would be very interesting to see if it is possible to create a fast algorithm.

*Memory requirements*: Preferably nothing should be pregenerated, but other than that, memory usage should match any ordinary game or application.

*Required detail*: Well, if you look at the image, you get the idea. It would be very nice though, if it was possible to zoom out and pan without having to calculate the map at the most zoomed in level first.

*Required types of objects and object properties to generate*: Nothing fancy, I am happy with the terrain according to the image above. But I admit I've been thinking of a similar setup where everything is a very very big city. That would be another question, though.

**EDIT 4:** Hopefully the final one.

OK, after reading a bit it seems that Perlin Noise is the way to go. I have one more question though (if someone cares to answer now that I have accepted one (actually two) answers :) ).

The perlin noise function takes doubles. What's the range for these doubles? [0-1[ ? Or can I happily send in my large integers?

Comment: Aren't *random* and *deterministic* somewhat contradictory?

Comment: @Dominic, they are, but you don't have truly random numbers but pseudo-random numbers and generators often have a way to 'replay' a random sequence.

Comment: No joke: I asked myself exactly the same question a few days ago: +1

Comment: @Dominic: On non-specialist computers random numbers are deterministic since they use pseudo random number generators based on mathmatical alogrithms. To get true random numbers (at least, what we think is truely random) requires a bit a of specialist hardware. www.random.org has some interesting stuff on randomness.

Comment: @Dom: Also don't forget that many applications that require random numbers (simulations as a prominent example) also *require* determinism as you must be able to exactly reproduce a simulation run. Also pseudo-random generators often allow better control over the statistical properties of the (pseudo-)randomness.

Comment: [Diablo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_%28video_game%29) game generates random level layouts. That was a one of the reasons I've played it dozens of times.

Comment: I think you will have to clarify a bit more then EDIT2 :) For example, see this link http://www.vterrain.org/ to grasp only the categories of the details that you could aim for.

Comment: @Nick: Diablo used player actions as entropy source. There is a speedrun that abuses it to beat Diablo in just a few minutes :-)

Comment: Because this is asked in the context of a game, do note that humans find isotropic fields fantastically boring.

Comment: @msw: If I understand the term "isotropic fields" correctly (meaning a world where everywhere looks about the same) I think that it would be amendable somewhat by using many different layers of altitude (where the large grained layers have bigger impact on altitude) so that some large areas are far up in the clouds and others are deep sea.

Comment: @Peter: you read me correctly, but I was too terse. Humans (and wasps for that matter) depend on unique features of a landscape to navigate successfully. If my guess is correct, changes in elevation won't do much to break isotropy. However a stand of trees or a distinctively shaped mountain or lake will break perceived isotropy over the whole range they are visible, but being in an array of mountains, lakes or endless forest won't. Creators of large MMOGs are keenly aware of this and go to much non-random, human, effort to break isotropy.

Comment: @msw: Yes, adding human effort to the mix is of course a good way to improve matters. However, for me the assumption is that there won't be enough resources for that. 

In one of my prototypes I used one layer with landscape and another layer with forests where I had a threshold value instead of elevation and wherever there was land and the threshold value was reached, I put a tree (or a stand of trees). This made reasonably  nice organic looking forests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, all terrain/world generators work in the way you described - they are able to produce vast (random-looking) worlds from a very limited input data (set of parameters).

So, you might want to put further constraints on your question.

If anything will work for you or if you are just begging to research - take a look at different focuses and approaches [here](http://www.vterrain.org/Elevation/Artificial/).

As for randomness/deterministic I am not sure that you really talk about randomness here and it can be a bit confusing, I think you only want to be able to create a lot of variations. So you might want to drop that from your search terms.

Take a look also at [procedural generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation) (especially 'see also' and 'external links').

Personally, I think there is a lot of promise in the concept of [terrain synthesis](http://www.howardzzh.com/research/terrain/) where you basically mix and match real terrain samples with some sort of transforming operations - which provides realistically looking terrain with desired properties.

**EDIT**:
Here's an [implementation](http://bocoup.com/processing-js/docs/index.php?page=Plasma%20Fractals) of 'plasma fractals' (mid-point displacement) in [processing](http://processing.org/).

If that is good enough for you then you could rework the algorithm to allow it to generate any part of the grid (I have a feeling it will boil down to hashing the coordinates to get random number seed around connecting lines, or everywhere).

Also you might work with different levels of detail with this method so that you can generate more detail closer to the point of view.

Comment: It appears the additional constraint is that he also wants to generate it on-demand - so each part of the map must be largely independent of the rest of it.

Comment: @snowlord, that should not be such a problem with terrain synthesis (nor with most of the other methods, the only one I can think of is erosion simulation that would be sensitive to your requirement; but even then there are ways to deal with it - pre-computing the grid as border conditions).

Comment: Also read on the links I provided; for your question I think it would be best to define the following: required performance, memory requirements, required detail (flight sim differs from game where you only crawl), required types of objects and object properties to generate (water/land - terrain type, vegetation - terrain cover, other artefacts - roads, rail, cities, etc...).

Comment: If you can provide a mockup of what you are aiming for as a picture it will be much more clear.

Comment: I will update my question in a while with a more detailed specification and also show what I mean with some images.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Perlin Noise, it is a type of deterministic random data named after it's inventor Ken Perlin. If you search for "Perlin Noise" or "Ken Perlin" you will find a ton of articles on procedural textures and landscape generation.

Comment: Funny, looking through my old code to find a generated map to link to (I didn't find one) I saw these classes, but didn't remember what they were for: PerlinSolidNoiseGenerator.java and SolidNoiseGenerator.java. They were written by Carl Burke, according to the javadoc.

Comment: Wording of this answer is wrong - Perlin Noise is a deterministic sequence of pseudo-random data, not the other way around (there are functions that are deterministic and pseudo-random that are not Perlin Noise). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

Answer (score 2):

Terrains are typically generated with fractals.

A simple method is Plasma Cloud algorithm, also known as [Midpoint displacement algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm). The general idea is:

1. Set some altitude values for the corners of the area.
2. Divide the rectangle into 4 smaller rectangles.
3. Calculate altitude for the new points as average of the surrounding points and add some random displacement value to that
4. Recursively divide each rectangle into smaller rectangles, and reduce the amount of displacement accordingly.

The random value is generated with a pseudo random number generator. If you give specific seed at the beginning, the same sequence of numbers is always generated.

Plasma cloud automatically generates smooth transitions, so no additional smoothing filter is needed.

Plasma cloud gives quite realistic landscapes, but they become boring in long term. Therefore, more complex algorithms (Perlin Noise, Ridged Perlin, etc.) may be used in addition. To get more variety, you could use one fractal (with low resolution) to adust the parameters of another fractal that calculates the actual values.

Fractals can be used to create textures and bumpmaps, too.

A good example of a program that generates landscapes with fractals and other procedural methods is [Terragen](http://www.planetside.co.uk/). Terragen generates photorealistic images, so it is slow, but it has OpenGL preview that creates the landscape on-the-fly.

**Edit:** The problem with Plasma Cloud is that you can not generate a single point (or a small area) without generating the whole area.
This is because it normally uses random number generator, which is dependent on the previous random number value.

However, you do not really need statistically good random number generator to generate terrain.
Thus, you could replace the rand function with some function that calculates the random number from X and Y coordinates instead of previous value.
Something like this (untested):

```
const int a = 0x7fffffff / 48271;
const int b = 0x7fffffff % 48271;

int displacement(int x, int y)
{
    int     seed, result;

    seed = x ^ ((y << 1) & 0x2AAAAAAA) ^ ((y >> 1) & 0x33333333);
    result = 48271 * (seed % a) - b * (seed / a);

    Return (result & 0xffff);
}
```

The above was modified from actual random number generator so that the seed is calculated from x and y. But maybe even some simpler function would be sufficient.

**Edit2**: To create **infinite world**, you can start for example with a rectangle of 10km x 10km. Use the displacement function above to set initial altitudes for the corners of the rectangle within which your target location is.
Then start splitting the squares with Plasma Cloud algorithm.
You only need to split and calculate those squares you are interested in, so you will quickly reach the target area (it is much like binary search).

Comment: I think Plasma Clouds was what brought me into this, but the requirement to set the border values makes it impossible to use, since these are unknown and must be generated too. Or is it possible to do away with them using some variant of Plasma Clouds?

Comment: If you only need a large (but not infinite) world, you could initially create a low resolution array of altitudes and seed values using plasma cloud, for example 256 x 256 array with 1km resolution. Then use plasma cloud to fill the 1x1 km area as needed. Or you could calculate the seed value for each corner of the 1x1 km square on the fly using some function f(x,y).

Comment: But the corners are not enough, are they? If I only have the corners, then two adjacent squares will not transition smoothly, if I am correct?

Comment: That is true. You would need to either modify the Plasma Cloud algorithm so that it would calculate edges first. Or replace the random number generator with some stateles function. I have now updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is pretty much the only way to do it - basically you've created a function, f, which gives geographical data for f(x,y). Of course, you can have several functions which you use to build up the terrain.

In addition to Perlin Noise, lookup fractal landscape generation. These can produce some very naturalistic loooking terrain.

Comment: I do not know very much about fractals, and I wonder if fractal landscape generation can be used to generate two overlapping rectangles separately without having any differences in the overlapping parts? I think that is kind of the most important aspect of my question.

Comment: And another thing, is smoothing really the way to go?

Comment: @snowlor, yes fractals can do that, for example random midpoint displacement fractal - it takes as input the border values. To make it perfectly fit you would have to modify a bit the usual procedure (which takes only the corners) and make it work with known overlapping values. They are also good for dynamic LOD. For smoothing - you will have to tweak yourself; some terrains are more smooth and some are less smooth.

Answer (score 0):

There are some papers listed [here.](http://www.vterrain.org/Elevation/Artificial/)

You mentioned Perlin Noise and that works well, especially if you need to generate terrains not topologically equivalent to a plane.

[The Science of Fractal Images](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387966080) has a section on spectral synthesis which lets you tune the results based on the desired fractal dimension.  The problem with this is that it's difficult to generate terrains other over a plane or torus.